# MessageHandler handles different message subtypes differently (can visitor pattern be applied?)

Tags: java, design-patterns

## Introduction

I'm working with Java 1.8. There is a lot of repetition in the `MessageHandler` class that I would like to remove but I'm having trouble implementing a fix.

#### External Code

I'm working with a message library that I should avoid changing. This library consists of these files:

`BaseMessage.java`

```
package external;

public abstract class BaseMessage {
    public void accept(MessageVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}
```

`AMessage.java`

```
package external;

public class AMessage extends BaseMessage {
}
```

`BMessage.java`

```
package external;

public class BMessage extends BaseMessage {
}
```

`MessageVisitor.java`

```
package external;

public interface MessageVisitor extends SendVisitor {
    default void visit(BaseMessage msg) {
        this.defaultAction(msg);
    }
}
```

`SendVisitor.java`

```
package external;

public interface SendVisitor {
    void defaultAction(BaseMessage var1);

    default void visit(AMessage msg) {
        this.defaultAction(msg);
    }

    default void visit(BMessage msg) {
        this.defaultAction(msg);
    }
}
```

#### Internal Code

`Entrypoint.java`

```
package example;

import external.AMessage;
import external.BMessage;
import external.BaseMessage;

class Entrypoint {
    MessageHandler handler;

    Entrypoint(MessageHandler handler) {
       this.handler = handler;
    }

    void handleMessage(BaseMessage message) {
        if(handler != null && handler.supports(message.getClass())) {
            if (handler.hasSeenBefore(message)) {
                // Log that we are skipping handling
                return;
            } else {
                handler.receive(message);
            }
        }

        // and do more unrelated things...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Entrypoint entrypoint = new Entrypoint(new MessageHandler());

        entrypoint.handleMessage(new AMessage());
        entrypoint.handleMessage(new BMessage());
    }
}
```

`MessageHandler.java`

```
package example;

import external.AMessage;
import external.BMessage;
import external.BaseMessage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class MessageHandler {
    private static Set<Class<? extends BaseMessage>> SUPPORTED_MESSAGE_TYPES = new HashSet<>(
            Arrays.asList(AMessage.class, BMessage.class));

    public boolean supports(Class<? extends BaseMessage> messageType) {
        // this sucks
        return SUPPORTED_MESSAGE_TYPES.contains(messageType);
    }

    private boolean hasSeenBefore(AMessage message) {
        System.out.println("Checking if I've seen an AMessage");
        // more complicated in the actual code
        return true;
    }

    private boolean hasSeenBefore(BMessage message) {
        System.out.println("Checking if I've seen a BMessage");
        // more complicated in the actual code
        return false;
    }

    public boolean hasSeenBefore(BaseMessage message) {
        // TODO: make better
        if (message instanceof AMessage) {
            return hasSeenBefore((AMessage) message);
        } else if (message instanceof BMessage) {
            return hasSeenBefore((BMessage) message);
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Tried to handle a message that is currently not supported: "
                    + message.toString());
        }
    }

    private void receive(AMessage message) {
        // do AMessage things
        System.out.println("Received an AMessage");
    }

    private void receive(BMessage message) {
        // do BMessage things
        System.out.println("Received a BMessage");
    }

    public void receive(BaseMessage message) {
        // TODO: make better
        if (message instanceof AMessage) {
            receive((AMessage) message);
        } else if (message instanceof BMessage) {
            receive((BMessage) message);
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Tried to handle a message that is currently not supported: "
                    + message.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

#### Question

As you can see, it's a pain to maintain the `MessageHandler`; specifically, the `hasSeenBefore` method has an `instanceof` that must be added to when another message is added, and a similar thing happens in the `receive` method. It is also really bad that the `supports` function keeps a separate list of those message types that must be updated when a new message type is added.

My hunch says that the Visitor pattern should be applied here more, but I'm having trouble implementing that.

- How can I remove all this duplicated logic so that I could add new message types to the MessageHandler cleanly?
- And how can `supports` check whether the message type is handled without maintaining a separate list?
- Is there anything else in the internal code which is not following best practices?

Comment: Can you post the complete code of MessageHandler and messages? It's not clear why you are casting.

Comment: Messages are casted into their subtypes so that they can be sent off to the subtype-specific handler methods. The messages contain some different fields which are checked in those subtype-specific handler methods. I think that posting the message contents would bloat this question up with details unrelated to my question, they are extremely big actually.

Comment: I should also mention that I am not authorized to release the full source code.

Comment: @karobar Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with enough code and / or context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site.

Comment: This is a bit borderline. I understand how this code is used and what the problem in question is and know a suitable answer. I don't think removing unrelated bits turns it into stub, obfuscated or hypothetical code. Making the requirements excessively limiting devalues this site as it will then become only a source for reviewing homework and interview question as practically no production code can be posted.

Comment: @AryanParekh There are times when the complete code can't be posted for legal reasons. In this case there was enough code for a good answer. Keep in mind the rules are that the OP can only post code they have written.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Alright!, I felt that this question lacked the necessary details for a review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem I see is that `MessageHandler` is solely responsible for knowing all the different message types and how they should be handled. If I was implemeting this I would create a separate MessageHandler subtype for each different message type and each subtype would only know about the existence of the specific message it handles. This reduces the dependencies each message handler has and thus makes testing and maintenance much easier. The main guide line here is the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)

To handle the selection of a correct MessageHandler in the `EntryPoint` class I would implement a `MessageHandlerRegistry` from which the EntryPoint can retrieve the correct handler for a message type by class. Essentially it is a simple facade for `Map<Class<? extends BaseMessage>, MessageHandler>`. To handle the case of unknown message type I would make the registry return a default handler which simply logs the error and throws an exception. That way the registry never has to return null values.

Populate the MessageHandlerRegistry in your bootstrap code and pass the reference to the EntryPoint class. The EntryPoint contains unnecessary null-checks. It seems obvious that the class can not function properly if it does not have a MessageHandler (or MessageHandlerRegistry in my version) so you should put the null check in the constructor and simply prevent the initialization of the EntryPoint if it's state is invalid. Make the field final so you know it will not be changed to null accidentally.

Comment: Hey thanks, this is very helpful! After retrieving a correct MessageHandler, would you send a BaseMessage to it and then cast inside of that MessageHandler, or is there some way to get a correctly-subtyped message to that handler. In other words, `registry.get(message.getClass()).receive(???)`

Comment: For some of the trickier bits I was able to get an implementation which satisfied me with the aid of Joshua Bloch's example of typesafe heterogeneous containers from Effective Java, modified with assistance from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541656/type-safe-heterogeneous-container-pattern-to-store-lists-of-items